# How can I display the shopping-cart-div on top of the product card in HTML and CSS?

Tags: html, css

I am making a shopping cart page for my E-Commerce website but Shopping Cart's div is hidden on bottom of the product card.

I asked to ChatGPT and it told me that I should replace the shopping cart's codes at the beginning of the HTML file but it did not work either.How can I solve my problem ?

`

```
<nav class="navbar navbar-expand-lg navbar-light bg-light">
  <a class="navbar-brand" href="#">EtheralWave</a>
  <button class="navbar-toggler" type="button" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#navbarNav" aria-controls="navbarNav" aria-expanded="false" aria-label="Toggle navigation">
    <span class="navbar-toggler-icon"></span>
  </button>


  <div id="asd" class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="navbarNav">
    <ul class="navbar-nav">
      <li class="nav-item active">
        <a class="nav-link" href="/">Homepage</a>
      </li>
      <li class="nav-item">
        <a class="nav-link" href="/Categories-Men">Men</a>
      </li>
      <li class="nav-item">
        <a class="nav-link" href="/Categories-Women">Women</a>
      </li>
      <li class="nav-item">
          <a class="nav-link" href="/Categories-Boys">Boys</a>
      </li>
      <li class="nav-item">
          <a class="nav-link" href="/Categories-Boys">Girls</a>
      </li>
      
      <form action="/Search" method="get">
          <input id="search-input" type="text" placeholder="Search" required>
          <button type="submit" id="search-submit" class="btn btn-light">
              <i class="fa-solid fa-magnifying-glass"></i>
          </button>                
      </form>
    </ul>

    
    <ul id="register-container" class="navbar-nav">
      <li class="nav-item">
          <a class="nav-link" href="#">Shopping Cart</a>
      </li>
    </ul>
  </div>
```

```
<!--Shopping Cart Product Snippet Begins-->


<div id='product-snippet' class='container'>

  <div id='photo-div'></div>

  <div id='name-div'>
    <h1>Name</h1>
    <p>[ShoppingCartProductName]</p>
  </div>

  <div id='color-div'>
    <h1>Color</h1>
    <div id='color-display-div' style='background-color: [ShoppingCartProductSnippetColor];'></div>
  </div>

  <div id='count-div'>
    <h1>Count</h1>
    <p>[ProductSnippetCount]</p>
  </div>

  <div id='price-div'>
    <h1>Price</h1>
    <p>[ProductPrice]</p>
  </div>

  <div id='delete-div'>
    <button id='delete-button'><i class='fa-solid fa-x'></i></button>
  </div>
</div>
```

```
<%-ProductCards%>
```

`

Comment: Could you please share styles and images?